# Angular get height of Component from app.component.html

Tags: html, angular

I uploaded my code into Stackblitz [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zsa6s5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fendlessblow.component.ts)

I want to get `<app-footer>` view in my `endlessblow.component.ts` by @ViewChild (line 24) or similar adnotation but the problem is this `<app-footer>` is placed in `app.component.html` so it is not a child of endlessblow.component.html so adnotation @ViewChild will not work here. If I put `<app-footer>` into endlessblow.component.html it works correctly but I want it to be places in `app.component.html`.

Kind regards Andrzej.

Comment: not understand your question

Comment: I want to get this component (<app-footer>) in my custom.component.ts by @ViewChild or similar adnotation but this is the problem, I dont know how.

Comment: What do you actually want? And why? You question is not clear

Comment: Where is custom.component.ts? What is the relation of this component in your app or with footer?

Comment: @Kenny I updated my code with link to my Stackblitz.

Comment: If you want to comunicate from EndlessblowComponent to your  app-folder you need to use an EventEmitter, or a service

Comment: @corsaro thank you. I used service and now it works. Topic can be closed.